# How to change my target <div> with another one through either CSS or jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page that can display hundreds of rows of data.  Each individual row of data can have anywhere from 1 to 9 options.  Clicking any 1 "option" will slide down a div and displays 2 possible actions for that row/option.  I am planning on putting AJAX functions for those actions.

Now, just for testing, I have a visible div call `.here`, in yellow, that I would like to be hidden. When the option is clicked, the `.here` open with my actions instead of the `<div>` that it currently opens.  It opens right under the options and that looks awful.  I know that is how my HTML/CSS is structured, but I don't know of any other way.  Any solution, whether HTML/CSS or jQuery would greatly be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $div = $(this).next('.dropdown-container');

    $(".dropdown-container").not($div).slideUp("slow");
    if ($div.is(":visible")) {
      $div.slideToggle("slow");
    } else {
      $div.slideDown("slow");
    }
  });

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    var p = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown').length

    if (!p) {
      $(".dropdown-container").hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.bind_Area {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

.bind_Name {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.dropdown-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: repeat-x center center #000000;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  color: #CCFF66;
}

.dropdown-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: none;
  background-color: gray;
}

.here {
  xdisplay: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div lass="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#">OPTION 00</div>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div>
          <div>Proceed</div>
          <br>
          <div>Cancel</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#">OPTION 01</div>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div>
          <div>Proceed</div>
          <br>
          <div>Cancel</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#">OPTION 02</div>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div>
          <div>Proceed</div>
          <br>
          <div>Cancel</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
<br>
<br>
<div lass="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#">OPTION 00</div>
      <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: none;">
        <div>
          <div>Proceed</div>
          <br>
          <div>Cancel</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#">OPTION 01</div>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div>
          <div>Proceed</div>
          <br>
          <div>Cancel</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#">OPTION 02</div>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div>
          <div>Proceed</div>
          <br>
          <div>Cancel</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here">
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
```

[View on CodePen](https://codepen.io/lepew/pen/mYYmOw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already got a perfectly good answer, but I'm going to give you a couple of alternatives and something to think about.

First up lets make this a little more semantic. You effectively have links to another section of the page, so lets use `<a>` tags with the `href` set to the page section. This option has no javascript and is perfectly functional, and could be enhanced with some javascript/jquery at your discretion.

```css
.bind_Area {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

.bind_Name {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.dropdown-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: repeat-x center center #000000;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  color: #CCFF66;
}


.dropdown-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
}

.dropdown-container:target {
  max-height: 1000px;
  display: block;
}

.here {
  position: relative;
  /*Children will be postioned relative to this */
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 85%;
  min-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div lass="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#option00">OPTION 00</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#option01">OPTION 01</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#option02">OPTION 02</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here">
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="option00">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 00</legend>
        <div>Proceed</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown-container" id="option01">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 01</legend>
        <div>Proceed</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="option02">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 02</legend>
        <div>Proceed</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
<br>
<br>
<div lass="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#option10">OPTION 00</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#option11">OPTION 01</a>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-link" href="#option12">OPTION 02</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here">
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="option10">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 10</legend>
        <div>Proceed</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="option11">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 11</legend>
        <div>Proceed</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown-container" id="option12">
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Option 12</legend>
        <div>Proceed</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
```

Now let's optimize this a little. In reality, you probably don't need a set of buttons for each option. You just need a way of passing the info to the ajax. I'm going to use a visible form field here so you can see it, but your could just as easily use a hidden field, or a data attribute that you AJAX call looks at. So in this version each "row" will have a set of action

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-link").on("click", function(){
    const tranSpeed = "slow";
    //OPTIONAL - hide all dropdown containers
   // $(".dropdown-container").hide(tranSpeed);
    //Get clicked option
    var selOption = $(this).data("selectedoption");    
    //Get next "here"
    var here = $(this).closest(".bind_Name").next(".here");
    
    //Populate stuff
    $(here).find("legend").text(`Option ${selOption}`);
    $(here).find("input[type=text]").val(`Option ${selOption}`);
    //TO DETECT IF DATA HAS CHANGED
    var dataChanged = $(here).data("seloption") !== selOption;
    $(here).data("seloption",selOption);
    //Show the dropdown if data changed 
    var target = $(here).find(".dropdown-container");
    //Cose Other containers
    $(".dropdown-container").not(target).hide(tranSpeed);
    if(dataChanged) {      
      $(target).show(tranSpeed);  
    }else{ //Or toggle it otherwise
      $(target).toggle(tranSpeed);
    }
    
    
  });
});
```

```css
.bind_Area {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

.bind_Name {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.dropdown-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: repeat-x center center #000000;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  color: #CCFF66;
}

.dropdown-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 5px;
}



.here {
  position: relative;
  /*Children will be postioned relative to this */
  margin-top: 5px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 85%;
  min-height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div lass="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-link" data-selectedoption="00">OPTION 00</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-link" data-selectedoption="01">OPTION 01</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-link" data-selectedoption="02">OPTION 02</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here">
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div>Proceed</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
        <input type="text">
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
<br>
<br>
<div lass="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-link" data-selectedoption="10">OPTION 00</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-link" data-selectedoption="11">OPTION 01</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-link" data-selectedoption="12">OPTION 02</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here">
    <div class="dropdown-container">
      <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>
        <div>Proceed</div>
        <div>Cancel</div>
        <input type="text">
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
```

Comment: OMG, this is great.  What this allows me are options like Proceed and cancel.  How do I make the option that I expand/open close when the same option is clicked.  It just re-opens it.

Comment: I've tweaked the JS version to achieve that. I can't think of a good way to do it with CSS only.

Comment: JS is just fine.  Okay, so yes this closes the "current" option, but if an option if opened on the first group, it is possible to open the next item too.  Is it possible to be brutal and have only 1 option open, all the rest get closed, regardless what is open.  I swear I feel so guilty asking because you have done an amazing job.

Comment: I'm going to leave you to see if you can work it out. Every thing you need is there. You just need to fine tune the logic. I'll give you a hint. Look at one of the lines I commented out. You might need to fine tune where it goes,.

Comment: OK, curiosity go the better of me. It was not as simple as I thought, but still only needed one line : `$(".dropdown-container").not(target).hide(tranSpeed);`

Comment: Jon, brilliant.  You can not believe how much your assistance has help.  Thank you !!!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using jQuery's [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the closest `.bind_Area` ancestor, and then finding the `.here` element within that ancestor element. I also suggest using [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to identify which option is active for a particular option area.

Here's a demonstration:

```js
$(function() {

  var $allHeres = $('.here');

  $(".dropdown-link").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $thisHere = $this.closest('.bind_Area').find('.here');
    var thisOption = $this.data('option');

    // close all that are not this one
    $allHeres.not($thisHere).slideUp("slow");

    // if this option area isnt set to this option...
    if ($thisHere.data('option') != thisOption) {

      // show this option area
      $thisHere.slideDown('slow');

      // set option area to current option
      $thisHere.data('option', thisOption);
      $thisHere.text(thisOption);

    } else {

      // toggle this option area
      $thisHere.slideToggle('slow');

    }

  });

});
```

```css
.bind_Area {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

.bind_Name {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.dropdown-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: repeat-x center center #000000;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  color: #CCFF66;
}

.dropdown-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: none;
  background-color: gray;
}

.here {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="0">OPTION 00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="1">OPTION 01</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="2">OPTION 02</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here"></div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
<div class="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="0">OPTION 00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="1">OPTION 01</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="2">OPTION 02</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here"></div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
```

Depending on the behavior you want in the options area, you may need to change its HTML and/or the events bound to its contents when you click various options.

Also, there seems to be a typo in your code:

```
<div lass="bind_Area">
```

should be:

```
<div class="bind_Area">
```

---

### Edit

Here's a version that slides up and back down when choosing a different option.
I'm also made it highlight the selected option, just for kicks.

```js
$(function() {

  var speed = 'fast';
  var $allHeres = $('.here');
  var $dropLinks = $('.dropdown-link');

  $dropLinks.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);
    var $thisHere = $this.closest('.bind_Area').find('.here');
    var thisOption = $this.data('option');

    // deselect links
    $dropLinks.removeClass('selected');

    // close all option areas
    $allHeres.slideUp(speed);

    // if this option area isnt set to this option...
    if ($thisHere.data('option') != thisOption) {

      // select this link
      $this.addClass('selected');

      // set option area to the current option
      $thisHere.data('option', thisOption);

      // slide option area up
      $thisHere.stop(true, false).slideUp(speed, function() {
        // set option area text and slide it down
        $thisHere.text(thisOption);
        $thisHere.slideDown(speed);
      });

    } else {

      // toggle this option and its area
      $this.toggleClass('selected', $thisHere.is(':hidden'));
      $thisHere.stop(true, false).slideToggle(speed);

    }

  });

});
```

```css
.bind_Area {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 7px 5px;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 0.875em;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

.bind_Name {
  display: flex;
}

.dropdown {
  display: block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.dropdown-link {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: repeat-x center center #000000;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 1px 1px;
  color: #CCFF66;
}

.dropdown-link.selected {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  display: none;
  background-color: gray;
}

.here {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 85%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="0">OPTION 00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="1">OPTION 01</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="2">OPTION 02</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here"></div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
<div class="bind_Area">
  <div class="bind_Name">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="0">OPTION 00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="1">OPTION 01</div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-link" href="#" data-option="2">OPTION 02</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of #bind_Name -->
  <div class="here"></div>
</div>
<!-- end of #bind_Area -->
```

Comment: WOW, thank you so much.  The explanation you provided is amazing.  Again, thank you.  Switching between "options" doesnt slideup or down, but  I can live without it.

Comment: Glad to help! I added a version that slides up and back down if you pick a different option.